# What is the difference between read, scan, and sink in polars?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-polars

In polars I see methods are `read`, `scan` and `sink` for the input.

For the output, we have `write`.

What is the difference between `read`, `scan`, and `sink` ?

https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/io.html

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could think of `scan` as a *"lazy read"* and `sink` as a *"lazy write"*.

- https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/concepts/lazy-vs-eager/

If we grab a CSV file as an example:

```py
df = pl.read_csv("https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/raw/main/py-polars/tests/unit/io/files/foods1.csv")
df.write_csv("foods1.csv")
```

`read` is eager and loads everything into memory giving you a DataFrame.

```py
>>> pl.read_csv("foods1.csv")
shape: (27, 4)
┌────────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ category   ┆ calories ┆ fats_g ┆ sugars_g │
│ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---    ┆ ---      │
│ str        ┆ i64      ┆ f64    ┆ i64      │
╞════════════╪══════════╪════════╪══════════╡
│ vegetables ┆ 45       ┆ 0.5    ┆ 2        │
│ seafood    ┆ 150      ┆ 5.0    ┆ 0        │
│ meat       ┆ 100      ┆ 5.0    ┆ 0        │
│ fruit      ┆ 60       ┆ 0.0    ┆ 11       │
│ seafood    ┆ 140      ┆ 5.0    ┆ 1        │
│ …          ┆ …        ┆ …      ┆ …        │
│ seafood    ┆ 130      ┆ 1.5    ┆ 0        │
│ fruit      ┆ 130      ┆ 0.0    ┆ 25       │
│ meat       ┆ 100      ┆ 7.0    ┆ 0        │
│ vegetables ┆ 30       ┆ 0.0    ┆ 5        │
│ fruit      ┆ 50       ┆ 0.0    ┆ 11       │
└────────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────────┘
```

#### LazyFrame

`scan` instead gives us a LazyFrame.

```py
>>> pl.scan_csv("foods1.csv")
<LazyFrame [4 cols, {"category": String … "sugars_g": Int64}] at 0x12E720880>
```

We can use [`LazyFrame.explain()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.explain.html#polars.LazyFrame.explain) to get query plan information.

```py
>>> print(pl.scan_csv("foods1.csv").explain())

  Csv SCAN foods1.csv
  PROJECT */4 COLUMNS
```

#### Optimizations

When using Polars' lazy API, *"Polars will run several optimizations on your query"*.

- https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/lazy/optimizations/

If we select a subset of columns, look at how the plan changes:

```py
>>> print(pl.scan_csv("foods1.csv").select("category", "fats_g").explain())
FAST_PROJECT: [category, fats_g]

    Csv SCAN foods1.csv
    PROJECT 2/4 COLUMNS
```

If we add some expressions:

```py
print(
   pl.scan_csv("foods1.csv")
     .select(pl.col("category") + "_foo", pl.col("category") + "_foo", "fats_g")
     .explain()
)
```

```py
 SELECT [
         col("__POLARS_CSER_2614548871777405161").alias("category"), 
         col("__POLARS_CSER_2614548871777405161").alias("category"), 
         col("fats_g"), 
         col("category").str.concat_horizontal([String(_foo)]).alias("__POLARS_CSER_2614548871777405161")
 ] FROM

    Csv SCAN foods1.csv
    PROJECT 2/4 COLUMNS
```

The optimizer has detected that `pl.col("category") + "_foo"` is repeated.

This allows it to execute it only once and cache it into a temporary column. (`__POLARS_CSER_2614548871777405161` in this case)

#### Streaming API

Polars also has a streaming engine which the `sink` methods use:

e.g. from the docs of [`.sink_csv()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/api/polars.LazyFrame.sink_csv.html#polars.LazyFrame.sink_csv)

> Evaluate the query in streaming mode and write to a CSV file.

> This allows streaming results that are **larger than RAM** to be written to disk.

> Streaming mode is considered **unstable**. It may be changed at any point without it being considered a breaking change.

- https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/concepts/streaming/